# Set up nice design pattern php

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am learning about design patterns. Currently I am working on a web service and I have time to structure the code, where I want to implement some design patterns.I already do watch to have each class doing one related thing, and write small functions with one or two parameters, but when it comes to design patterns, I am stuck.

My application is getting the data from external api, users, organizations and jobs. I have created these three classes, and currently they are all containing almost same curl call, same curl options and headers. And each of this class have one function, for organizations - getOrganizations, for users - getUsers ... Which all have same body, just a different curl call.

So I need just a reference, to a design patterns that can help me structure maintainable code.

Comment: Design patterns shouldn't be usef for the sake of design patternt.

Their implementation should be appropriate. They solve problems, don't create them.

E.g. you want to hide complex functionality of other vendors? Write your class and use adapter for it. You have different behaviour in one class and a lot of ifs? Use Strategy to make it more obvious. Etc. After some experience you usually know which one to use, but mastering them is a long term task.

Answer (score 2):

From reading your description you just need to practice OOP a bit more. (object oriented programming).

In this given example you could make a function that accepts the URL and either make all your requests extend from that base class that has that function 9r make a utility class with the curl logic and simply use that.

Also there are a ton of good php curl plugins on composer which can help you.

Comment: That was my intention, I just wanted to know is there some fancy design pattern that I could implement while still in development.